# Use Microsoft Access files in Android application

Tags: android, ms-access, connection

Is there any way to use a Microsoft Access files in an Android application?

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe there is any way to use a MS Access database with an Android application. Instead, you should probably consider using another database such as [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).

You could migrate your Access database to SQLite:

1. Export your Access database into text files, semicolon or comma delimited.
2. Open the [SQLite database browser](http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/) and chose File -> Import -> Table from csv file.
3. Browse for your text file and choose the appropriate delimiter. Click create.

Comment: "the SQLite database browser " - cannot find such a program on Android Market.

Comment: @Lumis : Android Market? - a quick search finds it.

Comment: That is not an android application and I don't think you have provided an answer, except in theory.

Comment: @Lumis: you don't need to convert the database actually on the Android Device, and therefore you don't need to run SQLite database browser on the Android Device!

Comment: @Lumis : if you have a better suggestion, please add an answer.

Comment: You are correct in the first half of your answer that android cannot read an access database, unless somebody has created a tool for it. However, how to convert an access database and import it into SQLite is a practical question, and either requires writing an android program to import an CSV or XML file into SQLite, or testing available tools on the market. I would know how to write a program, but have not tested any tools, so cannot safely recommend any.

Comment: @Lumis: "However, how to convert an access database and import it into SQLite is a practical question, and either requires writing an android program to import an CSV or XML file into SQLite" - that's incorrect. As I've pointed out you can do this using SQLite database browser  (Linked to above)

Answer (score 1):

If import isn't an option you can make a (PHP) webservice that queries the database. Then call upon that webservice in your android application.

This week i'll be starting a tutorial serie on http://p-xr.com that will explain just that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackcess, is pretty easy to use, but you can't execute queries.

http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/faq.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you are using Access 2010, then you can build web sites, and the results are massively scalable to the web in terms of simultaneous users. The so called Access web services are also coming to office 365. So with office 365 (still in testing) or with SharePoint 2010 you can thus publish Access forms to the web. Here is a video of mine, and note how the same Access application at the half way point is run in an standard browser.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AU4mH0jPntI

Note that no ActiveX or Silverlight is required (so it standard web compliant). I have tested the Access applications running on my windows 7 phone and the Access web application also runs well on my iPad (safari browser).

So, I do not see why the Access application would not work and run fine on an android phone. Note that when you publish the Access forms they are turned into xaml (.net zammel forms), and code you write in the Access form is converted into JavaScript. Reports are converted into sql server reporting services.

Comment: m using access as Back-End in a software developed in vb6.I need to connect access as back end with android so that i can connect android with software.in-short interchange data from software to android and vise-versa.

Answer (score -1):

Use a windows machine and access access over a remote control tool.
For a bigger scenario, you can use Windows Terminal Services.